# How to display null values as N/A in table when the data type is decimal

Tags: birt, display, isnull

I would like to display null values as N/A in the report when the data type is decimal. I've tried to click on the cell and set the following under Map, but didn't work; still got blank cells as a result:

[image: map]

Is this because of the data type or something else?

Also, I've tried to use the following expression but this time the values could not be displayed:

```js
if (row["STATEMENT2"]== null)
{
'n/a';
} else {
row["STATEMENT2"];
}
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Botond

Answer (score 0):

I used the "Map" for this Problem as well.
My solution works in all of my Reports:

`[Your_Field]` **Equal to** `null`

(Null written without "" or '')

Then type the value to Display in the bottom field.

Hope this helps.